# Anyone know a way to use Chromecast as a screen for my TV

Tags: chromecast

I have a poorly placed modem and need to connect my Chromecast to my TV. No HDMI cable I own can reach. Is there a way I can use the raspberry pi through the Chromecast? Thanks

Comment: your going to have to elaborate on the problem, what can connect to your tv and what can't, because in your second sentence you state that no cdmi cable can reach. so is it the pi you want to connect to your chrome cast? where does the modem distance come into all this?

Comment: I can connect my Chromecast to my TV. I have no screen for my raspberry pi so what I want to do is use my TV and the Chromecast as the screen. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: it is not a problem, i have written my answer below

Comment: not a problem, please mark the answer as correct by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you own an android phone you can install the chrome cast app on your phone and can then install an ssh app from the App Store, pretty much any will do. then you want to cast the screen of your phone and launch the ssh app, and connect to the pi, to do this your going to need to find the ipaddress of the pi, by accessing your modem page, then entering that data into the ssh app along with the default credentials which will be username:`pi` password:`raspberry` which will allow you to connect to the pi.

I do recognize that this is an in optimal solution, but it is the most practical one, as without a monitor on the pi, you probably won't be able to get any code on the pi to connect it to the chromecast.